# Batch task execution every 500ms

Tags: node.js, reactjs, async.js

Hi have a **react/node** app and that receives messages from outside the app. Upon receiving a message, my react app shows a desktop notification and pings a sound. I have this working well, except that if the app receives multiple messages (ie., 10 messages) all within a short window, I see multiple desktop notifications and multiple sounds.

I obviously need the app to process the 10 incoming messages, but I am having trouble finding a way to "batch" the notification alerts into a single notification.

I have looked at `async/cargo`, but that actually looks like the opposite of that I want. **I need to be able to say *"send a notification and sound once for each set of messages that the app receives within 500ms"*.**

I'm not looking for code help, but more of conceptual help. Are there packages that help make something like this easier?

Comment: To me it sounds like your app needs to have  a "cache" notification mechanism that will put it in a queue first and:
- if 500ms not elapsed and new notification arrived put it in a queue
- if 500ms elapsed w/o new notifications PING

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to throttle or debounce the call to display the notification and ping. Lodash and rxjs are libraries that offer this capability.

Throttling a function means the function can't/won't be called more often than the throttle time, i.e. not more than once every N milliseconds, whereas debouncing waits until a specified time has elapsed that the function *wasn't/isn't* called to then finally call that function, i.e. every time the function is called it waits N milliseconds before calling callback, timer resets if called before expiration.

- [lodash throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle)
- [lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)
- [rxjs throttle](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/throttle)
- [rxjs debounce](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/debounce)

rxjs has a steeper learning curve, but if you're already using it or event streams/observables then it'll fit right in. Lodash will work with existing functional callbacks.